# Can ASP.NET MVC4 run on IIS7.5, .NET Framework 4?

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC3 application, and I want to upgrade to MVC4 after its RTM.

But I don't have the right to change the production server environment. It's a Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS7.5 and .NET4 installed.

Is it possible to upgrade to MVC4 without changing framework version and IIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can deploy MVC 4 application on a server with IIS 7.5 and .Net 4

Comment: -1 and that's it? A link to a book and correct answer? I don't think so.

Comment: He asked whether he can or not; so the answer is simply `YES` and a reference to a book if you challenge. simple